# Need to remove the battery and reinstall windows every time i shut down the PC

Tags: display, bios, motherboard, battery

I built a PC with the following hardware a couple days ago :
-Corsair 80plus gold
-i5 12600 12th gen ,
-Tuf gaming B660 plus wifi D4
Everything works fine until i decide to shut down the PC.
I have to actually remove the battery and reinstall windows every time i shut down the PC otherwise all i get is a black screen.
I can restart it without any issue after installing windows but i soon as i shut it down, it's over, i have to remove the battery, put it back in, and reinstall windows again.
I replaced the CR2032 battery with a new one and updated the Bios just in case but it didn't do the trick.
Not sure what causes it... never had that issue before.

Comment: You have to reinstall Windows after shutting down your machine? What type of GPU do you have.  I would have to find the video, that likely explains the behavior, but a black screen sounds like a display to display adapter issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP notes issue resolved after updating Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.
Seems like updating windows did the trick.
You can mark it as solved.